# how to create an arraylist of xml attribute values using xpath

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I have an `xml` like this:

```
   <A>
    <b>
     <c id="1">
     </c>
    </b>
    <b>
     <c id="2">
     </c>
    </b>
   </A>
```

Is it possible to create an `ArrayList` of the attributes `id` of `<c>`. `<c>` can have `1....n` occurrences.

`ArrayList` will have values `[1,2]` for this example.

I am looking for a solution preferably in `xpath`, if not in `xslt` otherwise `java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible XPath expression is `/A/b/c/@id` to select the `id` attributes, the type of that XPath expression is a node set of attribute nodes in XPath 1.0 and a sequence of attribute nodes in XPath 2.0. In XPath 2.0 you could also use `/A/b/c/@id/number()` to get a sequence of number (double) values or `/A/b/c/@id/xs:integer(.)` to get a sequence of integer values. To map any such result to a Java ArrayList you will however have to look at an XPath API.